# pdfbox jpg detail information in pdf file

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a jpg file that has the following information in detail tab

1. Title : Foo
2. Subject : Testing

I have insert this jpg file into pdf using pdfbox and save the pdf file. After that I read that pdf file and find image `PDImageXObject` but unable to find the `Title and Subject` information.

any update ?

Comment: This is EXIF info. You'll need to get some library that analyses that, e.g. this one https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/

Comment: Might also be part of the metadata around the IIOMetadata class from java itself.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr when I extract that image from pdf. all information has been lost.

Comment: The ExtractImages utility has a "-useDirectJPEG" option, use that one, or this code: `InputStream data = pdImage.createInputStream(Arrays.asList(COSName.DCT_DECODE.getName(),
            COSName.DCT_DECODE_ABBREVIATION.getName()));
 IOUtils.copy(data, outputStream);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(data);` and your outputStream now has a JPEG image.